# Salesforce Bulk API error: InvalidBatch: Records not processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce

I'm sending a batch of contacts through Restforce gem via Bulk apu

```
response = connection.post("/services/async/#{connection.options[:api_version]}/job/#{job_id}/batch") do |req|
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8'
  req.headers['X-SFDC-Session'] = connection.options[:oauth_token]
  req.headers['Content-Length'] = payload.length.to_s
  req.body = Restforce::UploadIO.new(StringIO.new(payload), 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8')
 end
```

Where payload is:

> "AccountId,FirstName,LastName,Description,Phone,Email\n0011510001DXiOVAA1,Matt,Cali,Nice
>   guy,+14150000000,matt@example.com\n0011501001DXiOWAA1,Michael,Michael,very nice guy,+14150000001,michael@example.com\n"

I'm getting an error: "InvalidBatch: Records not processed"
The only response that I get.

How can I see what's exactly wrong with my batch?
It used to work before, and at some point it stopped working. I made sure I added all permissions on a trial account I created.

Request/response data:

> struct Faraday::Env method=:post, body=#Restforce::Mash batchInfo=#Restforce::Mash apexProcessingTime="0"
>   apiActiveProcessingTime="0" createdDate="2015-12-06T23:06:28.000Z"
>   id="*SOME_ID*" jobId="*SOME_ID*" numberRecordsFailed="0"
>   numberRecordsProcessed="0" state="Queued"
>   systemModstamp="2015-12-06T23:06:28.000Z" totalProcessingTime="0">>,
>   url=#https://na22.salesforce.com/services/async/33.0/job/*SOME_ID*/batch>,
>   request=#, request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday
>   v0.9.2", "Content-Type"=>"text/csv; charset=UTF-8",
>   "X-SFDC-Session"=>"*SOME_SESSION_ID*", "Content-Length"=>"233",
>   "Authorization"=>"*SOME_AUTH_ID*"}, ssl=#, parallel_manager=nil, params=nil,
>   response=#> @url=#URI::HTTPS
>   https://na22.salesforce.com/services/async/33.0/job/*SOME_ID*/batch>
>   @request=#Faraday::RequestOptions timeout=600 seconds,
>   open_timeout=600 seconds> @request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday
>   v0.9.2", "Content-Type"=>"text/csv; charset=UTF-8",
>   "X-SFDC-Session"=>"*SOME_ID*", "Content-Length"=>"233",
>   "Authorization"=>"*SOME_ID*"} @ssl=#Faraday::SSLOptions verify=true>
>   @response=#Faraday::Response:0x007f22b44a78 ...>
>   @response_headers={"date"=>"Sun, 06 Dec 2015 23:06:28 GMT",
>   "set-cookie"=>"*SOME_DATA>",
>   "location"=>"/services/async/33.0/job/*SOME_ID*/batch/*SOME_ID*",
>   "content-type"=>"application/xml", "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked",
>   "connection"=>"close"} @status=201>>, response_headers={"date"=>"Sun,
>   06 Dec 2015 23:06:28 GMT", "set-cookie"=>"*SOME_ID*",
>   "expires"=>"*SOME_ID*",
>   "location"=>"/services/async/33.0/job/*SOME_ID*/batch/*SOME_ID*",
>   "content-type"=>"application/xml", "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked",
>   "connection"=>"close"}, status=201>

Comment: Would be more use posting this at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

- Check that API enabled
- Check that Salesforce schema is not different
  from expected
- Check Bulk Jobs in Salesforce UI (Setup ->
  Administrative Setup -> Monitoring -> Bulk Data Load Jobs)
- Since you get batch id, you could fetch
  batch state (https://instance_name-api.salesforce.com/services/async/APIversion/job/jobid/batch/batchId) and see if there are more details in there